# Dataset for training text classifier

Tags: text-mining, text-classification

I'm new to data mining and I am trying to build a classifier that is able to classify student theses abstracts into a predefined set of categories under the area of Computer Science, e.g. Machine learning, Image Processing...etc.
I do not have enough classified abstracts to be used as a training dataset so would you please direct me to a dataset that can be used for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DBLP data (downloadable from http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/) to generate a list of publications. Based on conferences/journal you can generate your classes e.g. MLJR is alway Machine Learning.

The abstracts you can acquire using:
https://github.com/arc12/Text-Mining-Weak-Signals/blob/master/Abstract%20Acquisition%20Scripts/DBLP%20XML%20fetch%20abstracts%20.pl